# make the content appear horizontally in buddypress login widget

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, buddypress

I put the Buddypress login widget in the header, but it has a vertical layout  while I would like to have it to display horizontally. 
[This is what I mean](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lc2r0.png)

I would like to have the username part next to the password part and this one next to the rest but in a horizontal layout (bacause it's a headerbar and I don't want it to be huge).

This is the actual code:

```
<aside id="bp_core_login_widget-7" class="widget widget_bp_core_login_widget buddypress widget clearfix"><h3 class="widget-title"></h3>


        <form name="bp-login-form" id="bp-login-widget-form" class="standard-form" action="https://www.example.com/wp-login.php" method="post">
            <label for="bp-login-widget-user-login">Username</label>
            <input type="text" name="log" id="bp-login-widget-user-login" class="input" value="">

            <label for="bp-login-widget-user-pass">Password</label>
            <input type="password" name="pwd" id="bp-login-widget-user-pass" class="input" value="" spellcheck="false" autocomplete="off">

            <div class="forgetmenot"><label for="bp-login-widget-rememberme"><input name="rememberme" type="checkbox" id="bp-login-widget-rememberme" value="forever"> Remember Me</label></div>

            <input type="submit" name="wp-submit" id="bp-login-widget-submit" value="Log In">


                <span class="bp-login-widget-register-link"><a href="https://www.example.com/register/">Register</a></span>



        </form>


    </aside>
```

I have the chance to add custon CSS, but I have no idea if this is achievable with just CSS. I was able to reach kind of a result by using:

```
-webkit-columns: 3; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
-moz-columns: 3; /* Firefox */
columns: 3;
```

but the problem here is that after you login, the user image and name take the place of the login form and they get divided in 3 columns too.